# Nuxt router dynamic param for every route as a suffix

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

I'm using Nuxt2. I want to have a routing which have dynamic param for each route and this param can be dynamic. For example:

```
/users/london
/posts/london
/products/berlin
/products/apple-watch/berlin
/products/samsung-flip/berlin
/products/samsung-flip/london
/products/samsung-flip/tokio
```

Is there any possible solutions for this?

I tried to extend my routes in `nuxt.config.js` with following

```
    extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
      routes = routes.map((route) => ({
        ...route,
        path: route.path + '/:region',
      }))
    },
```

But I ended up with error 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `extendRoutes` is in the `router` object?

The following is an example for users, make sure to push to routes and not overwrite it.

```js
    router: {
        extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
            routes.push({
                name: 'users',
                path: '/users/:region',
                component: resolve(__dirname, 'src/pages/PATH_TO_COMPONENT/_id.vue'),
            });
            routes.push({
                name: 'products',
                path: '/products/:region',
                component: resolve(__dirname, 'src/pages/PATH_TO_COMPONENT/_id.vue'),
            });
            routes.push({
                name: 'samsung-flip',
                path: '/products/samsung-flip/:region',
                component: resolve(__dirname, 'src/pages/PATH_TO_COMPONENT/_id.vue'),
            });
        },
    },
```

Comment: Firstly, I'm sure extendRoutes is in the router object in the `nuxt.config.js` file. Secondly, what will happen to my old routes? If they are still accessible, then this option may not work or I should find a way to redirect, right?